# Docker+Mesos+Marathon on windows 7/8/10

Tags: mysql, docker, mesos, marathon

I have windows 7/10 machine and i have docker terminal running on the same which is using boot2docker as VM , i have fetched mesos(master/slave) , marathon images from the docker hub and i am able to open marathon and mesos GUI's , now my ultimate goal is to deploy a docker image or mysql DB to the mesos slave , since i am very new to this technology i am not getting any step through even after following many tutorials.
Can someone please help me by mentioning the step by step procedure for the same.

**UPDATE:**

When I try to deploy an application which is just a sleep command it's getting stuck on marathon and in deployment state forever.
below is the logs which i got from marathon. if anyone can help resolving this issue it will be much appreciated.

```
[2016-02-02 10:42:10,616] INFO activating matcher ActorOfferMatcher(Actor[akka://marathon/user/launchQueue/1/4-test-app#-897119850]). (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManager
Actor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12494)
[2016-02-02 10:42:10,617] INFO Received offers WANTED notification (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12494)
[2016-02-02 10:42:10,618] INFO => revive offers NOW, canceling any scheduled revives (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12494)
[2016-02-02 10:42:10,618] INFO 2 further revives still needed. Repeating reviveOffers according to --revive_offers_repetitions 3 (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.act
or.default-dispatcher-12494)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a beginner I would not recommend experimenting with Mesos on any Windows. Although a partnership [has been announced](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/server-cloud/2015/08/20/microsoft-and-mesosphere-partner-to-bring-mesos-container-orchestration-to-windows-server/), it is definitely not ready. Here's a [meta task tracking progress of Mesos on Windows](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-3094).

Until Mesos is ported to Windows I would recommend starting a VirtualBox machine or renting an hourly Linux instance for experiments.

Comment: Hi @Tombart ... i tried deploying sample command line application got success in that.. however my doubt is even windows setup is using boot2docker as VM wouldnt that be sufficient .. i have already gone through the links you have provided. but switching to a linux environment is not an option with me right now .
I have seen in some websites people tried similar setup as me and got success .. but for me its not working i am still not able deploy docker images to Mesos